Can't import CSV files in S3 into ClickHouse
I refer to the official documentation for example: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/tutorial
sql looks like:
INSERT INTO trips
SELECT * FROM s3(
    'https://datasets-documentation.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/nyc-taxi/trips_{1..2}.gz',
    'TabSeparatedWithNames', "
    `trip_id` UInt32,
    `vendor_id` Enum8('1' = 1, '2' = 2, '3' = 3, '4' = 4, 'CMT' = 5, 'VTS' = 6, 'DDS' = 7, 'B02512' = 10, 'B02598' = 11, 'B02617' = 12, 'B02682' = 13, 'B02764' = 14, '' = 15),
    `pickup_date` Date,
    `pickup_datetime` DateTime,
    `dropoff_date` Date,
    `dropoff_datetime` DateTime,
    `store_and_fwd_flag` UInt8,
    `rate_code_id` UInt8,
    `pickup_longitude` Float64,
    `pickup_latitude` Float64,
    `dropoff_longitude` Float64,
    `dropoff_latitude` Float64,
    `passenger_count` UInt8,
    `trip_distance` Float64,
    `fare_amount` Float32,
    `extra` Float32,
    `mta_tax` Float32,
    `tip_amount` Float32,
    `tolls_amount` Float32,
    `ehail_fee` Float32,
    `improvement_surcharge` Float32,
    `total_amount` Float32,
    `payment_type` Enum8('UNK' = 0, 'CSH' = 1, 'CRE' = 2, 'NOC' = 3, 'DIS' = 4),
    `trip_type` UInt8,
    `pickup` FixedString(25),
    `dropoff` FixedString(25),
    `cab_type` Enum8('yellow' = 1, 'green' = 2, 'uber' = 3),
    `pickup_nyct2010_gid` Int8,
    `pickup_ctlabel` Float32,
    `pickup_borocode` Int8,
    `pickup_ct2010` String,
    `pickup_boroct2010` String,
    `pickup_cdeligibil` String,
    `pickup_ntacode` FixedString(4),
    `pickup_ntaname` String,
    `pickup_puma` UInt16,
    `dropoff_nyct2010_gid` UInt8,
    `dropoff_ctlabel` Float32,
    `dropoff_borocode` UInt8,
    `dropoff_ct2010` String,
    `dropoff_boroct2010` String,
    `dropoff_cdeligibil` String,
    `dropoff_ntacode` FixedString(4),
    `dropoff_ntaname` String,
    `dropoff_puma` UInt16
") SETTINGS input_format_try_infer_datetimes = 0

DBeaver throw exception:
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Code: 115. 
DB::Exception: Unknown setting input_format_try_infer_datetimes. (UNKNOWN_SETTING) (version 22.1.3.7 (official build))

Is there a problem with the version? Or what configuration is required to solve it?

version 22.1.3.7 is a very old version. Please one of the supported versions listed here - https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/SECURITY.md

According to https://github.com/search?q=repo%3AClickHouse%2FClickHouse%20input_format_try_infer_datetimes&type=code
Upgrade your clickhouse to 22.8+
